# Bizarre MSSQLSMS font size behavior on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sql-server

After several years, MSSQLSMS 2012 has suddenly started ignoring the font size setting:

[image]

I've tried changing it from 8 points to 4 and to 40, with no observable change in displayed font size. Restarting didn't help. I can manually set the zoom from 100% to 70% and it's usable, but I'd like not to have to bother.

This is the error message I got on startup when the issue began:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

The type initializer for 'System.Windows.Media.Fonts' threw an exception. (mscorlib)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

No FontFamily element found in FontFamilyCollection that matches current OS or greater: Windows7SP1 (PresentationCore)

------------------------------

No FontFamily element found in FontFamilyCollection that matches current OS or greater: Windows7SP1 (PresentationCore)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be an issue corrected in KB4074880, ["Security and Quality Rollup for .NET Framework 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, and 4.7.1 for Windows 7 SP1 and Server 2008 R2 SP1"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4074880/description-of-the-security-and-quality-rollup-for-net-framework-4-6-4).

> On January 18, 2018, update 4074880 was released to replace update 4055002 for .NET Framework 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, and 4.7.1 for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. Update 4074880 no longer contains the issue that is described in the following Knowledge Base article:
>
> 4074906 - "TypeInitializationException" or "FileFormatException" error in WPF applications that request fallback fonts after you install the January 9, 2018, .NET Security and Quality Rollup (KB4055002)

There's no download for KB4074880; I found it in [Catalog Update under KB4055532](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=4055532).

[KB4019990 is a prerequisite](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4019990).